# alloc init inside methods

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two methods in the same application

The first is in the Fraction Class

```
 -(Fraction *) divide: (Fraction *) f
 {
 Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
 result.numerator = numerator * f.denominator
 [result reduce];
 return result;
 }
```

the second is in the calculator class

```
-(Fraction *) performOperation: (char) op
   {
 Fraction *result;
 switch (op) {
 case '+':
 result = [operand1 add: operand2];
 break;
 .
 .
 .
 .
 etc

break;
}
accumulator.numerator = result.numerator;
accumulator.denominator = result.denominator;
return accumulator;
}
```

Why does the first need to alloc and init the *result instance variable
in the first method but not the second? Is it because it's calling another method
 [result reduce] or because its returning a value? or something else?
The second method seems to simply instantiate a temp variable result of type Fraction
without initializing or creating memory.

Thanks

Comment: Your code snippets are incomplete. Where do operand1 and 2 and accumulator come from?

Comment: operand1 and 2 are properties declared in calculator class

Comment: I am working through a book tutorial and just trying to figure out why some of the Fraction objects are created inside methods while others are synthesized properties. Why wasn't result created as a property? In the tutorial each of the add,subtract,multiply and divide methods create result objects. why not just do it once in properties?

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion stems from an inaccurate way of thinking about what's happening. It's clearer if you think about it this way:

Rather than "alloc init'ing the result variable", what you're doing is "alloc init'ing a Fraction object, and then assigning its address to the result variable".

The creation of the object is separate from assigning its address to the variable, and the object is not the same as the variable, the variable just refers to it.

So in the second case, you don't need to alloc init a Fraction because you're not trying to create a new empty Fraction, you're getting a pointer to a Fraction from somewhere else (the -add method in this case) and using it.

Also, your -divide method doesn't look right. You never set the denominator on your new Fraction.

Comment: ok thanks I see the difference now. I chopped out some of the code in an attempt to make it a simpler question. The logic is incomplete in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You already `alloc`ate and `init`ialize the object inside the method and return a pointer to it. You then assign this pointer to a local variable - you don't need to allocate more memory for it.

Also, in case you don't use ARC, don't forget to either `autorelease` your `result` inside your `-divide` method, or `release` it in the `-performOperation` method after using it. Otherwise your app will leak memory.

Comment: This doesn't sound correct. What if the method without the alloc is called before the one that has no alloc?